# why javascript refuses to work more than once?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two separate links that call same function. They are used to load different external html doc into body of main one. They work correctly by themselves. But when one doc is loaded another one refuses to. What is a problem guys?

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="decorNavi" onclick ="xmlRequest('about')" >ABOUT</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" class="decorNavi"  onclick ="xmlRequest('contactus')" >CONTACT US</a
</li>
```

Script:

```
function xmlRequest(target) {

    var targetClick;

    targetClick = target;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlRequest.open("GET", targetClick + ".html?=" + Math.random(), true);


    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (xmlRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlRequest.status == 200) {

            document.getElementById("midContainer").innerHTML = xmlRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlRequest.send();
}
```

Comment: Does this persist if you `var xmlRequest;`?

Comment: Try debug your `xmlRequest.status` it maybe other if from cache

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: what error you are getting in console.?

Comment: I agree with Paul, try putting a `var xmlRequest;` before you use it, perhaps declare it right after `var targetClick;`.

Comment: @Sumeet Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Comment: @PaulS. Yes, it helped can you explain why this error occurs?

Comment: With the `var`, `xmlRequest` is a local variable inside the _function_ `xmlRequest`, so the _var_ version **shadows** the _function_ version inside the _function_. When it's next invoked from the global `xmlRequest`, the local variable "doesn't exist", so isn't there to get in the way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overwriting your function declaration inside your function:

```
function xmlRequest(target) {
```

and

```
xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

It fires once, and then replaces the function with the xmlRequest. Name the second one something else.

Comment: There is no such thing as overloading in javascript?

Comment: @Amal.A Remember that _JavaScript_ is not a strongly typed language; the interpreter would have no way of knowing how to decide which you want if there was such a thing as overloading.

Comment: Paul S is right.  Have you ever seen this kind of thing in a JS function?:if (!param) { param = 0; }

Comment: @MattCampbell i'm to used to java, so eventually i become to lazy and expect interpreter to do a job for me =)

Comment: Hi Amal, Hope I was clear in my comment.  For my example, the function declaration'd look like this: 'function afunc(param) {...}'  If you called afunc with just 'afunc()' it would work without passing 'param' into it.  The '(!param)' test checks to see if 'param' was passed in (i.e., if it was even defined).  So if you define 'afunc' again it will replace the prev. declaration.  In short: you can't use the same name for a function on the same web page regardless of the function signature without replacing the prior declaration.

Answer (score 2):

As Mike Robinson said, you are overwriting your function. Use an other name for your function. As easy as that.

```js
function xmlRequest(targetClick) {

    var xmlRequest; // xmlRequest is no more a global. 

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlRequest.open("GET", targetClick + ".html?=" + Math.random(), true);

    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlRequest.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("midContainer").innerHTML = xmlRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlRequest.send();
}
```

JSbin: http://jsbin.com/kehaxexo/2/

Comment: This still creates global variables

Comment: You're right, just need to add `var xmlRequest;` no? :)

Answer (score 1):

The name of you function "xmlRequest" and object defined in it are the same. change it to something else.